# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't detect second monitor

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, vga, multiple-monitors

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04. Suddenly, my second monitor isn't detected on Ubuntu. It worked fine before. When i try using Windows 7, it is detected. I'm using HP Pavilion G4 1212tx AMD ATI Radeon.

Why isn't it detected? Is there a problem with my VGA card?

Comment: are they plugged into one card or two seperate cards? have you installed additional drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Open **Additional Driver** , then try to use **X.org X server**. Or if you already use that you can switch to a new driver corresponding to installed VGA card. Most of the times **X server** works but I don't guarantee about other drivers to respond properly.
Then, in **Displays** check that both displays are ON.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to install drivers for AMD ATI Radeon. Search AMD ATI Radeon and install the driver from their website. Your computer came with preinstalled Windows and Graphics card driver. But when you install ubuntu, it doesn't know you have a graphics card so you need to install the driver.

I had to do the same thing with mine but with nvidia graphics card driver. Once you do that, it'll detect your second monitor.